# How i do combobox selected value can work?

Tags: c#

I have 3 comboboxes. `cb1` `cb2` `cb3`.

If `cb1` has selected value, but others hasn't.It is okay.

If `cb2` has selected value and , but others hasn't.It is okay.

If `cb1` and `cb2` has selected value, but the other hasn't.It is okay.

If `cb2` and `cb3` has selected value, but the other hasn't.It is okay.

If `cb1` and `cb2`and `cb3` has selected value .It is okay.

If `cb3` has selected value, but others hasn't. It's not okay.

If `cb1` and `cb3` has selected value, but the other hasn't.It's not okay.

If it is okay do something, but if it isn't okay show an messagebox with error.

How can i do that? My code doesnt't work.
My code:

```
if (cb1.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb2.SelectedIndex == -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    //do something
}
else if (cb2.SelectedIndex == -1 && cb2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    //do something
}
else if (cb1.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    //do something
}
else if (cb1.SelectedIndex == -1 && cb2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    //do something
}
else if (cb1.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    //do something
}
else if (cb1.SelectedIndex == -1 && cb2.SelectedIndex == -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    //messagebox
}
else if (cb1.SelectedIndex > -1 && cb2.SelectedIndex == -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    //messagebox
}
```

Comment: Is it OK if *all three* `cb1`, `cb2`, `cb3` have selected value?

Comment: yes, i will edit my post, sorry.

Comment: "My code doesn't work." ' what not working, have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: What about case when all comboBox don't have selected value? Did you try debug your code? What is wrong with it?

Comment: When all combobox dont have selected value nothing  will happen. it is okay. 
Yes i try debug. i put it main nothing happens.

Comment: I can see just *one* not OK condition "If cb3 has selected value, but others hasn't. It's *not okay.*" in the task description, but *two* `//messagebox` fragments in the code provided

Comment: what do you mean "nothing happens" ? none of the condition satisfies?

Comment: Don't show message box, and don't do what in the if statemant.

Comment: @orodene well it's simple `SelectedValue` returns an `Object` when nothing selected it will return `null`

Comment: i selected value in the form when i debug, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

In the first `else if` block, you check cb2 twice. If you change the first cb2 to cb1, you get the same conditions as the topmost if condition. Something's wrong with that, I think.

Anyway, since you have far less fail blocks than success blocks, I would only check for the fails. Display a messagebox in that case and abort/return. Otherwise continue execution outside the if-conditions with doing something.

The two bottom conditions can be combined. The state of cb1 doesn't seem to matter if cb2 is unselected and cb3 is selected; that combination is always a fail.

So with the information given in your question, my code would be something like:

```
if (cb2.SelectedIndex == -1 && cb3.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    //messagebox
    return;
}

//do something
```